# adding an ouput line to an existing praat script

Tags: praat

I am using an existing praat script for speech rate ([Nivja de Jong and Ton Wempe, 2008](https://sites.google.com/site/speechrate/Home/praat-script-syllable-nuclei-v2)) that outputs speech rate along with other variables in the Praat info window. It saves the files it uses compute such variables, including pitch and intensity data. I want to add output lines following the original script (sort of to piggyback off of it for the information it already has). I tried running the following lines based off the manual commands I did to get such pitch and intensity values. I then tried to name these commands and print them in the output file.

```
# print a single header line with column names and units
printline soundname, int_mean(dB), int_sd(dB), int_min(dB), int_max(dB), pitch_mean(Hz), pitch_sd(Hz), pitch_min(Hz), pitch_max(Hz)

selectObject: "Intensity ML_001_TD_TD_hobbies_L"
int_mean(dB) = Get mean... 0, 0, "energy"
int_sd(dB) = Get standard deviation... 0, 0
int_min(dB) = Get minimum... 0, 0, "Parabolic"
int_max(dB) = Get maximum... 0, 0, "Parabolic"
selectObject: "Pitch ML_001_TD_TD_hobbies_L"
pitch_mean(Hz) = Get mean... 0, 0, "Hertz"
pitch_sd(Hz) = Get standard deviation... 0, 0, "Hertz"
pitch_min(Hz) = Get minimum... 0, 0, "Hertz", "Parabolic"
pitch_max(Hz) = Get maximum... 0, 0, "Hertz", "Parabolic"


# summarize results in Info window
printline 'soundname$', 'int_mean(dB)', 'int_sd(dB)', 'int_min(dB)', 'int_max(dB)', 'pitch_mean(Hz)', 'pitch_sd(Hz)', 'pitch_min(Hz)', 'pitch_max(Hz)'

endfor
```

However, I keep getting an error at the first manual command line saying "Unknown unfunction 'int_mean' in formual. Line 5 not executed." But when I compare to similar commands in their script that work, I cannot find the problem with how I assigned the variables and why it won't run.

Any advice on where I went wrong and how I can get it to execute these outputs?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is really a programming question, not a question about linguistics.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Linguistics, a scientific study of natural languages, its phenomena, currents, theories, or its history, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a different command than "printline".
Other Praat script commands that can be used to print results are:

writeInfoLine

appendInfo

fileappend

See the Praat scripting guide on writing to the Info Window: http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Scripting_6_2__Writing_to_the_Info_window.html